# Converting string to type date or type time

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, types, type-conversion

I have 2 columns in the database. One is of type Date and another is of type Time(7).

I am updating the values in the database through front end. For conversion I am doing:

```
(columnName of type Date) Start_Date = TextBox1.Text;
(columnName of type Time) Start_Time = TextBox2.Text;
```

And its giving me an conversion error from string to time... How can I convert it?

Comment: and can you post the value that you are trying to convert to time?

Comment: If the date and time are related to each other, they really ought to be stored as a single column of type `datetime2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `DateTime` object from your textboxes and assign that to the columns. You  could use [`DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx). Or also [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), depending on how much control you want to retain over the parsing of the date.

Comment: Thanks... one more query... how do you verify whether the datetime field is null... I mean if temp = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text) then how do you see whether "temp" is null??

Comment: You can't. You should probably check TextBox1.Text first to see if it is empty.